# iOS calendar is behaving strangly

Tags: ios, calendar

I want to create a recurring event on iOS calendar but the event is not getting created properly. The event dates go beyond the specified dates.

**There is event start and end date.**

[image]

**This is when event should repeat it.**

[image]

**And this is what I see when I search for the result I just added**

As per my understanding event should have been ended on 25-July-2016, but the even is repeating itself to 2017.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the`End Date = Never`.  The `Starts` and `Ends` are the appointment times, not the dates.  If you want it to be from 7pm to 8pm then `10-May-2016 8:00pm` would be the `Ends`.

When you want to stop the repeating event, put that date in the `End Date` row.  So you would have `End Date` as `25-July-2016 8:00pm`.